# Spring failed to lazily initialize a collection of role when doing a request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a problem when trying to get all `Players` from my DB.
The error I get is:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role
```

I tried to either change the `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` to `EAGER`, but it didn't help, when I debug the `getAllPlayers()` from `controller`, so the part:

```
ResponseEntity.ok().body(playerInterface.getAllPlayers());
```

the result of debugging seems to be fine:
[image]

In the Postman I can see:

[image]

My `Player` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Player {
   ...
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Club club;
   ...
}
```

My `Club` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Club {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "club", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Player> players;
    ...
}
```

My `PlayerController`:

```
@RestController
public class PlayerController {
    private final PlayerInterface playerInterface;

    public PlayerController(PlayerInterface playerInterface) {
        this.playerInterface = playerInterface;
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/players")
    ResponseEntity<List<Player>> getAllPlayers() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(playerInterface.getAllPlayers());
    }

}
```

`PlayerInterface`:

```
public interface PlayerInterface {
    List<Player> getAllPlayers();
    Player addPlayer(Player player);
    boolean deletePlayer(String id);

}
```

`PlayerService`:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PlayerService implements PlayerInterface {

    final PlayerRepository playerRepository;
    final ClubRepository clubRepository;

    public PlayerService(PlayerRepository playerRepository, ClubRepository clubRepository) {
        this.playerRepository = playerRepository;
        this.clubRepository = clubRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Player> getAllPlayers() {
        System.out.println(playerRepository.findAll());
        return playerRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Comment: Show us PlayerInterface

Comment: @grigouille I edited my post, and included `PlayerInterface`

Comment: I don't understand the error message "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role" as I don't see role involved at all. Otherwise though, I don't see how your player-club entities can be converted to JSON without a stack overflow, as the player->club reference then club->player would cause a circular loop. You have to tell JSON parser how to handle it - the most common way is to mark one side with the @JsonIgnore annotation so it isn't serialized. JSON serialization knows nothing about your JPA mappings and fetch types. You might then try eager on the player->club relation

Comment: @Chris I'd go further than that and just avoid bidirectional associations entirely. They pretty much add nothing compared to just using a repository method to get the objects from the other direction, and are a major headache to keep in sync.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see the code of `PlayerRepository` and `ClubRepository` but I assume your session was closed before you were trying to get the data.
If its session issue you can resolve it by adding `@Transactional` to `getAllPlayers`or you can prepare separate method to get the necessary data